# JQuery can't disable button after enabled

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have the code below on a Rails 5 app. Simply put, it enables a button after it verifies if a field is present for that user.  Works fine, but problem is once button is enabled, won't disable the button again if the user changes their option to another choice that is not present.  It still remains enabled.  So essentially the code runs only once, but doesn't run again every time the user makes a change.

How do I fix this?

```
      $("#collection-modal-btn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');       
  $('#get-folder').change(function() {
    var empty = false;
    if ($("#get-sub").val().length == 0) {
            empty = true;
        }
    if (empty) {
        $("#collection-modal-btn").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $("#collection-modal-btn").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

HTML below:

```
    <form action="/client_sub_folders/images" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="2avzd+POdKL8g7/2SPKGDay49ov6cMkZ8XJAo3yf4dKNGpxKXmi/UE8p2m69lh/jZj+lFpLk72nVo+kqLBMU6Q==">
    <select id="get-folder" name="client_folders[client_folder_ids]"><option value="">Choose a Collection</option>
<option value="19">Tester</option>
<option value="6">Jake's Jones</option></select><br>
    <select id="get-sub" name="client_sub_folders[client_sub_folder_ids]" style="display: inline-block;"><option value="8">Master Bedroom</option></select>
    <input type="hidden" name="client_sub_folders[w_artisan]" id="client_sub_folders_w_artisan" value="574" class="carpet_to_add">
    <div class="submit-to-folder">
      <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Add Carpet" class="btn btn-standard" id="collection-modal-btn" data-disable-with="Add Carpet"> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `$("#collection-modal-btn").prop('disabled', true);` use `.prop()` they value will be `true or false`

Comment: @dgreen22 If I am not wrong then you need to disable button as soon as user enter anything right?

Comment: @Manishh Not exactly - Need it to check if a field has an object every time user changes their input (it's a dropdown menu of objects)

Comment: After seeing your HTML i saw that you having only one option so else condition will never satisfied.To make the code work properly add an empty option like below:-

`<select id="get-sub" name="client_sub_folders[client_sub_folder_ids]" style="display: inline-block;">
 <option value="">Choose a Bedroom</option><!-- add this as an option-->
 <option value="8">Master Bedroom</option>
</select>`